# how to update a xml using a id in C#2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, nodes

I am trying to update a xml on basis of id.

my xml file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <HeaderDetailID>0</HeaderDetailID>
    <FirstName>
    </FirstName>
    <LastName>
    </LastName>
    <EmployeeID>
    </EmployeeID>
    <Department>
    </Department>
    <Postion>
    </Postion>
    <Application>
    </Application>
    <Filter>
    </Filter>
    <AreaorCountryorStation>
    </AreaorCountryorStation>
    <NetworkDomain>
    </NetworkDomain>
    <Action>
    </Action>
    <NameOfController>
    </NameOfController>
    <Status>
    </Status>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <HeaderDetailID>1</HeaderDetailID>
    <FirstName>Basant</FirstName>
    <LastName>Basant</LastName>
    <EmployeeID>Basant</EmployeeID>
    <Department>Basant</Department>
    <Postion>Basant</Postion>
    <Application>
    </Application>
    <Filter>
    </Filter>
    <AreaorCountryorStation>Basant</AreaorCountryorStation>
    <NetworkDomain>Basant</NetworkDomain>
    <Action>
    </Action>
    <NameOfController>Basant</NameOfController>
    <Status>Request Completed</Status>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Now I try to fetch id from hidden field and get It on server side to update the node name status.

```
for (int i = 0; i < DateData.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    string iRecordID = DateData[i];

                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    string filepathsUpdate = Server.MapPath("Contact.xml");
                    xmlDoc.Load(filepathsUpdate);
                    XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/CATALOG/CD[ID=" + DateData[i] + "]/Status");
                    node.InnerText = "Request Completed";

                    xmlDoc.Save(filepathsUpdate);

                }
```

It works locally fine but on server it doesn't work.

Can I close the connection in XML file

I feel like xmlDoc.Save not working

Comment: Code appears to be fine. Do you get an exception? Did you verify the path `Server.MapPath` returns is correct?

Comment: I put it in try and catch but it doesn't come with any exception but its working locally fine but on server it works sometimes and sometimes not...Is their any method I can update the node of CD element in XML Apart from  XmlDocument

Comment: If it's working occasionally, then the code is probably fine. I'll probably investigate other software on the server (virus scanners, firewall). If you have the opportunity, check if the code works on similar servers. If you insist on changing the code, you could have a look at `XmlWriter` class for example.

Comment: Are you always using the same xml file when it works and when it fails?

Comment: Yes I am using the same XML file.